# вывести предыдущие строки по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'fruit': ['pear','pear','banana','banana', 'pear', 'pear','apple', 'apple', 'cherry','cherry'],
        'fruit_type': ['unknown','pear','unknown','one', 'two', 'one','one', 'apple', 'cherry','unknown'],
'country': ['unknown','usa', 'unknown','usa', 'unknown','ghana','unknown', 'russia', 'albania','bolivia'],
'id': ['022','022','022', '011','011', '011','011', '011', '6','6'],
'month': ['unknown','march', 'unknown', 'october','october', 'january','july', 'unknown', 'january','unknown']       
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['fruit','fruit_type','country', 'id', 'month'])
df
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вывести предыдущую строку предшествующую строке , где `месяц=unknown`, и если предшествующие строки идут **подряд** с одинаковым значением `fruit_tyue`, то нужно вывести все эти предшествующие строки.

Как можно это сделать?

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Шаг 1**

Найдем строки, которые предшествующую строке , где `month=='unknown'`

Здесь стоит использовать метод [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), который позволяет сдвигать индекс.

```
df[df['month'].shift(-1)=='unknown']
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат сохраню в столбец `unknown_prev`, он нам пригодится.

```
df['unknown_prev'] = df['month'].shift(-1)=='unknown'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 2**

Теперь найдем строки, в которых значение в колонке `fruit_type` идут подряд. Это нам тоже пригодится в будущем, поэтому сразу сохраню в столбец `g`

Тут тоже используется метод `shift`, но как раз просравнивать между собой соседние строки позволяет [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html)(бинарный !=), [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) переводит это в численное представление, а точнее возвращает совокупную сумму по столбцу.

```
df['g'] = df['fruit_type'].ne(df['fruit_type'].shift()).cumsum()
df
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 3**

Теперь задача сводится к тому, чтобы вытащить данные, у которых одинаковые `g` и один из `unknown_prev` равен `True`. Я просто сгруппировала по `g` и нашла максимальный 'unknown_prev' для каждого, а тут выбор невелик или 0(False), или 1(True). Затем просто по сути выбрала нужные колонки:

```
df[df['g'].map(df.groupby('g')['unknown_prev'].max())]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осталось только удалить лишние столбцы.

Решение одним куском:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'fruit': ['pear','pear','banana','banana', 'pear', 'pear','apple', 'apple', 'cherry','cherry'],
        'fruit_type': ['unknown','pear','unknown','one', 'two', 'one','one', 'apple', 'cherry','unknown'],
'country': ['unknown','usa', 'unknown','usa', 'unknown','ghana','unknown', 'russia', 'albania','bolivia'],
'id': ['022','022','022', '011','011', '011','011', '011', '6','6'],
'month': ['unknown','march', 'unknown', 'october','october', 'january','july', 'unknown', 'january','unknown']       
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['fruit','fruit_type','country', 'id', 'month'])

df['unknown_prev'] = df['month'].shift(-1)=='unknown'
df['g'] = df['fruit_type'].ne(df['fruit_type'].shift()).cumsum()
res = df[df['g'].map(df.groupby('g')['unknown_prev'].max())]
res.drop(['unknown_prev', 'g'], axis=1, inplace = True)
```